# salesforce - overriding a standard object detail page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have overriden lead object standard detail page with my vf page using  tag and added my own stuff(like jquery popup)...will there be any problems like security,permissions,layout modifications because of this override...

for instance , if admin modifies the detail page layout will that be reflected since its overriden by my vf page ????

similarly what about permissions/security and other stuff for that page ?? will that also be reflected ???

thanks for your responses..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have is `<apex:detail>` to represent the object's detail page, it will conform to what is configured - assuming as Kevin mentioned you use `with sharing` in your class definition to make sure that the same access rights are respected.

But yes, the detail page layout changes will be *inherited* when you use the Visualforce tag `<apex:detail>`.

Answer (score 0):

If your admin makes changes to the standard detail page, those changes will not be reflected in your VF page. For example, if they make a field required on the Page Layout (not at the object-level), that will not be reflected on your VF page. However, if they make a field required on the Lead Object itself, this is enforced at the database-level and will also be required in your VF page. The same is said for field-level-security.

If you have a controller extension created for your page, you need to make sure that you define your class using the "with sharing" modifier if you wish to keep your sharing rules in-tact for that VF page. Otherwise your controller may access records not normally shared with the user on the VF page.

Comment: but i have only one line <apex:detail> tag inside my vf page and it should take care of those layout changes right ????